# Choosing between Classic Team Site and Modern Team sites for migrating our on-premises team sites to SharePoint online

Tags: sharepoint-online, migration, team-sites, modern-team-site

I am a bit confused on which site templates we need to use for migrating our on-premises 2013 sites (Team Sites and Enterprise wiki sites) to SharePoint online. where we are using a third party named share-gate to do the migration.

Now i did this test migration as follow:-

1. Inside the on-premise farm, we have 3 team sites and 2 enterprise wiki sites.
2. the 3 team sites are being used as follow:-

   - First Team site, is our company home site, which contain a general discussion list to add announcements + general document library + general quick links.
   - Second Team Site, have 5 subsites, where each sub-site represent a department. each sub site have a document library + custom list to track tasks.
   - the third team site, have sub-sites for each project (25++ subsite), and each subsite have 7 different lists for managing risk, issues, improvement, FAQ, etc..
3. so inside our online tenant i created, the following:-

   - 3 classic team sites
   - 2 enterprise wiki sites.
4. i migrated the sites, and the result was promising, as almost every thing were migrated correctly/smoothly.
5. so i thought  i can now do a real migration.
6. but lately i came across a new site template named "Modern team site" https://support.office.com/en-us/article/create-a-team-site-in-sharepoint-online-ef10c1e7-15f3-42a3-98aa-b5972711777d .
7. which seems provide many user friendly UI enhancement and better mobile support. but from my first reading that those modern team sites are mainly sites to be used by group of people to collaborate together, rather than being sites for managing different departments and different projects as in our case.

so now i have the following points which i am unable to understand:-

1. based on my above description for the current team sites. can those be migrated as modern team sites? or they best suites to be migrated as classic team sites?
2. now to keep user experience the same (for the on-premises and online), so if we migrate the team sites as classic online team sites. then will we be able to chnage the classic team site, to be a modern team site in the future?
3. now i am a bit confused if our current classic online team sites, are actually a modern team sites??. as our migrated document libraries are being rendered in new experience (we have the option to switch back to classic experience), as follow:-

[image]

also i am able to create modern site pages, as follow:-
[image]
so can i say that our current classic team sites, are classic team sites with modern UI capabilities !!